# Vim periodically reverts to system version

Tags: apt, xubuntu, vim, clipboard

(I am running Xubuntu 18.10.)

I want clipboard support in my Vim, which isn't present in the `vim` package in apt, so I compiled Vim myself with `+clipboard`. I then proceeded to install it using `checkinstall`. This works fine.

However, after some time, I will notice my Vim no longer supports the clipboard. `vim --version` shows `-clipboard`; it's clear that it has reverted to the system version.

What could be causing this? Where can I look to figure out what is making my installed version disappear? `checkinstall` produces a .deb file which I can install using the Software GUI app; but when it reverts, (my build of) Vim is no longer listed as installed in that app.

---

I am experiencing another issue with something happening periodically, which I include here only because it might be relevant. I have set proxy variables in various places including `/etc/environment` and `/etc/profile.d/office_proxy.sh`, because I need these for the office. When at home, I will typically manually go and comment all of these out & relog to disable the proxy. However, **some time after logging in, the proxy variables will reinstate themselves**. I'm 99% certain it's not a script of mine that is setting the proxy; I suspect Xubuntu is doing this somehow. Again, I only mention this here because this is another seemingly time-based behaviour.

Comment: It looks like it might just be apt "upgrading" my Vim to the apt version. I have applied `apt-mark hold vim`; let's see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: If you know the solution, then you should add it as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by apt overriding my own version of Vim whenever I ran it. The solution was to use `apt-mark hold vim` to tell apt not to try to upgrade Vim.